# php continue write to file with new line break

Tags: php, file

How could I break a new line after each execution of write in data into text file?

the file is show records in none new line break:

> countryId:20, productId:332, status:1, opId:188, xId:pdgje9876, countryId:20, productId:334, status:0, opId:188, xId:pfgje3455,

and this is the output I needed:

> countryId:20, productId:332, status:1, opId:188, xId:pdgje9876,
>
> countryId:20, productId:334, status:0, opId:188, xId:pfgje3455,

```
$txt = "log.txt";
$fh = fopen($txt, 'a') or die("can't open file");

foreach($obj as $key => $value) {
    print "$key => $value<br>";

    $stringData = $key.":".$value.", ";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);

}
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `"\n"` at every line end.

```
$txt = "log.txt";
$fh = fopen($txt, 'a') or die("can't open file");

foreach ($objects as $obj) {
  foreach($obj as $key => $value) {
    print "$key => $value<br>";

    $stringData = $key.":".$value.", ";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
  }
  fwrite($fh, "\n");
}
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add "\n" to the end of the line.

```
$txt = "log.txt";
$fh = fopen($txt, 'a') or die("can't open file");

foreach($obj as $key => $value) {
    print "$key => $value<br>";
    if ($key == "xld") {
        $stringData = $key.":".$value.",\n"; // Will add new line after xld key
    } else {
        $stringData = $key.":".$value.", ";
    }
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);

}
fclose($fh);
```